# Intercept only service, not implementation in Windsor

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, interceptor, castle-dynamicproxy

I have this code:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For(typeof(MyServiceInterceptor<>)),
    Component.For<IMyService<string>, MyServiceImpl<string>>()
        .Interceptors(typeof(MyServiceInterceptor<>))
        .Anywhere
)
```

Windsor generates proxy class for MyServiceImpl<>. But I want to intercept only IMyService<> methods. How to do it?

Comment: What version is that?

Comment: version is 3.0.0.4001